# How convert numeric value to date in R (same as Short date in excel)?

Tags: r

I want to convert numeric date format to date. I.E. I have value 44109, but want to convert it to 2020-10-06. How is it possible?

Comment: See `help("as.Date")`, in particular the *Examples* there.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
> as.Date(44109,origin = "1900-01-01")
[1] "2020-10-07"
```

Answer (score 0):

this works as well

```
x <-  as.POSIXct(44109 * (60*60*24), origin="1899-12-30", tz="GMT")

"2020-10-05 GMT"
```